# Enable actions (click, selecting text, whatnot) outside of bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The default bootstrap modal adds a full page element that when clicking closes it. With `data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"` you can disable this functionality and so that clicks outside the modal and the <kbd>esc</kbd> key do nothing.

I'd like to use a bootstrap modal that allows me to click, select and perform all the normal functions on the page without dismissing it. The only way to dismiss it would be to click buttons on the modal (`x` or cancel for example).

How can I use a bootstrap modal like that?

```
<!-- Example modal **without** the functionality I want -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Settings</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Settings</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button id="loadpage" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three steps I took to achieve the desired effect. My modal is prepended to the body, the steps may differ if yours is not.

1. Bootstrap appends a `div` element to the body (`body > .modal-backdrop`). It has the styles that cause the white "overlay" effect. This whole element can be deleted or the styles overridden.
2. A class is added to the body, `modal-open`. This has the css `overflow: hidden;`. Either remove that class, or override the css.
3. The actual modal will also need some css added. `width` or `max-width` worked for me. (makes scrolling of the modal work)

   - `#myModal {max-width: 300px;}`

Don't make those changes for every modal, use a trigger to restrict them to a specific one.

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
    // Remove overlay and enable scrolling of body
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open").find(".modal-backdrop").remove();
});
```

The above causes some "flashing" with the removal of `.modal-backdrop`. If that is unwanted, overriding the styles with css or preventing the default bootstrap action may be best.

Answer (score 0):

I saw no solution for what you ask and I needed to have this feature, I did a function to do that.
It's working with jquery ui draggable element but you can move out any code related to that and it should work as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/wyf3zxek/

```
modalDraggableClickOutside('#modal-example', 'iframeLoaded', 'Modal shown');
```

Note that it's not working very well in an iframe (such as js fiddle) : in an iframe you need to move the modale once

Comment: "I saw no solution for what you ask" – what's wrong with my solution? I mean, as an alternative answer, sure, but were you having trouble with my one?